# How to match the textbox value then update the specific data into firebase web

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database:

[image: inside the image is the data inside the firebase]

```js
var carplate = document.getElementById("carplate").value;


var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('ClampedCar');

firebaseRef.orderByChild('carplate').equalTo(carplate).update({stat:"Unclamped"});
```

```html
<label style="color: #f2f2f2">Car Plate Number</label> <br/>
<input type="text" name="carplate" id="carplate" maxlength="8" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only call `update()` on a database reference. To get the reference to the nodes matching your query, you must first execute the query.

```
var query = firebaseRef.orderByChild('carplate').equalTo(carplate);
query.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    child.ref.update({stat:"Unclamped"});
  })
});
```

The `snapshot.forEach()` loop is needed since the query may match multiple children. **If** that is not the case, i.e. your `carplate` is already unique, you may consider changing your data model to be:

```
ClampedCar
  carPlate1: "Clamped"
  carPlate2: "Clamped"
```

With this model you don't need a query to change the status and can just do:

```
firebaseRef.child(carplate).set("Unclamped")
```

Comment: I'd probably check `snapshot.exists()` or `snapshot.hasChildren()` for that, but aside from that... yeah, should be possible.

Comment: I tested the statement. it only run the if condition when enter the different car plate which does not exist in the database

Answer (score 0):

I would to do the validation on the matching. it is possible to do like this?

```js
var exist =query.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    child.ref.update({stat:"Unclamped"});
  })
});


if(exist){
 window.alert("Status updated")
 
}else{
 
 window.alert("Car Plate doesnot match");
 
}
```